# Why is debounce time needed?

Tags: angular, debouncing

I am implementing a search function in a data table in my app. For that, I found a tutorial where I can add the debounceTime so the search doesn't happen instantly (in my example 150 milliseconds).

What is the purpose of this?

The reason I'm asking is that when I change the debounce time, from 150 milliseconds to 0, the search seems much more smooth and "nicer".

My guess is, it is better for the runtime or servers? This is an insignificant question but still woke my curiosity for better understanding coding in general and in my case Angular.

```
    fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
            debounceTime(150),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            if (!this.dataSource )
            {
                return;
            }
            this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
        });
}
```

Comment: A few reasons - the main one is that the search function might slow your app down. This could cause an appreciable lag as someone is typing. Another reason is that the update process might be slower than the typing causing desyncronization between the app state and user expectations: user pushes key "a" - request is sent, user pushes "b" - request is sent, "a" response received, "b" response received. So the "a" response might be presented in the app after the user typed "b"

Comment: If you're hitting an api after every keystroke, then your server will need to process a lot of requests in a short amount of time. Now, if you have many users and they all search at the same time? You'll be out of resources pretty soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debounce time is needed mainly in search inputs where the search is performed automatically. You dont want the search to run after every letter you type only when you finish typing. The debounce will operate the function only if from the first call to the function there has been x time that the function wants called again.

a Debounce time of 300ms will do the trick.

You can also read about throttle and the difference between debounce and throttle here :[throttle vs debounce](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)